# Is it Possible to display only the Date when printing out a DateTime List?

Tags: c#, datetime

```
this.reportTextBox.Text += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, notEqualValue);
```

This Line of code will print out all of the Tuple values within this list. It will be displayed looking something like this:

> (02/12/14 00:00:00, hello)

I only wish to display the Date function of my DateTime method. So it should look like:

> (02/12/14, hello)

Is this possible?

The initialization of the Tuple can be seen below.

```
 Tuple<DateTime, string> a = new Tuple<DateTime, string>(data_entryA.Date, tag_a_name);
```

Comment: `ToShortDateString()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: [Comments are not for answers](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can format your dates

```
var values = notEqualValue.Select(x => string.Join(",",x.Item1.ToString("d"),x.Item2));
this.reportTextBox.Text += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, values);
```

[`"d"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#ShortDate) gives you the date in format  `6/15/2009`, but it's culture sensitive. So if you have a different culture try using `DateTime.ParseExact` method with a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).